# Custom status codes in a web api, almost asking if we can override the response message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I am developing a web API (asp.net) and I have been given instructions that we want to provide users with a list of error/ok codes so they can process this when calling our APIs.

Initially, I thought we will just use the `httpStatusCode` however we have been informed that what we really want is a load of custom calls that our API users will use. That got me thinking, we could probably create an error object like this

```
public staus
{
  public string code {get; set;}
  public string message {get; set;}
}
```

Then we can use the bad request for errors so something like

```
return (IHttpActionResult)Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new status{"-30001", "something specific is not right"});
```

or something like this for ok

```
return (IHttpActionResult)Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new status{"0", "Everything is great"});
```

But how do I actually go about doing this for the whole API? I have looked online and I know we can send custom messages, but I also need to send custom codes. Also when it is a 200 so OK I still need to also send the actual data as well.

Any direction on where to go to try and complete this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yo ucan return a standard HTTP Error and then put your new custom status message in the HTTP body of the response.   You then have two choices  (1) Just read the body of the response when the status code is not 200 OK (2) Format the body like and Action Result so the controller can parse the error.

Comment: ok, but how do i do that? most importantly i want to also send across a status code of all good or something even when a status of 200 is hit. Along with this i would also need to send the results of the call. Something is telling me i should add this to the header.

Comment: It can be either in the header or the body.  First design what your body will contain.   Then you are just adding body information when sending and parsing the body when you are receiving.